# What do unusual symbols "@" and ".\/" in off-chain code mean?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

I was wondering about syntax I am not used to in the off-chain code.

What does `@` mean in the following context?
`logInfo @String $ printf "made a gift"`

What does `.\/` mean in the following context?
`type GiftSchema = Endpoint "give" Integer .\/ Endpoint "grab" ()`

I guess that it has to do to the multiple GHC extensions invoked in Plutus code but I do not have the time to understand each and everyone of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@String` is from `TypeApplications`. `logInfo` has type `logInfo :: forall a effs. Member (LogMsg a) effs => a -> Eff effs ()`, so `logInfo @String` fixes `a` to be `String`. (That this is needed here is because of another extension `OverloadedStrings`, so `"made a gift"` is not necessarily of type `String`)

`.\/` is not from an extension, but [an operator defined by the `row-types` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/row-types-1.0.1.2/docs/Data-Row.html#t:.-92--47-).